# Mysql Query sum and group by not showing a row with null values

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I have this query:

```sql
SELECT Customer, SUM(SoldUnits) AS SoldUnits
FROM Uploads
WHERE Year = 2021
AND Week = 11
GROUP BY Customer;
```

And Returns me:

| Customer | SoldUnits |
| --- | --- |
| CUSTOMER A | 55 |
| CUSTOMER B | 32 |
| CUSTOMER D | 17 |

`CUSTOMER C` exist, but it doesn't have data for the `week 11` and I want to show `CUSTOMER C` with 0 `SoldUnits`. How Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table does have all customers you want to appear in the report, you could do a conditional summation and remove the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT Customer,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Year = 2021 AND Week = 11
                THEN SoldUnits ELSE 0 END) AS SoldUnits
FROM Uploads
GROUP BY Customer;
```